# Sort Different Columns(different datatypes) in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Scenario: I have a following table were I like to sort two different columns in simple way.

TestTable

```
List Val
--------
a     20
c     10
b     30
```

Result:

```
List Val
--------
a    10
b    20
c    30
```

I have tried the following query but it fails to sort both columns

```
Select Col, val 
From Dummy 
Order By Col, val asc
```

But I have gotten the desired result on the below query

```
With Q As
(
    Select 
       Col, Val,  
       Row_Number() Over (Order By Col) TT1 
    From TestTable
),
Q1 As
(
    Select 
        Col, Val, 
        Row_Number() Over (Order By Val) TT2 
    From TestTable
)
Select 
   Q.Col, Q1.Val 
From 
   Q, Q1 
Where 
   TT1 = TT2
```

But I need to know is there any other simple way to achieve it. Can we able to get result thru JOIN.

Comment: I deleted my answer, I didn't notice your query without NoDisplayName's edit. Sorry.

Comment: Also why are you doing this.

Comment: Can you add some more data? The intent of your sorting is unclear. From the data provided, an alphabetic sort on List would suffice, but from your sample query, it appears that there's more to it than that.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you can do something like this:

```
SELECT ListSort.list, ValSort.val
FROM 
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY list) AS ID,  list
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY list
) ListSort INNER JOIN
(
SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY val) AS ID, val
FROM TestTable
ORDER BY val
) ValSort ON ListSort.ID = ValSort.ID
```